# JQuery Scroll Script is creating free Space at the bottom of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, whitespace

Why does my script create free space at the bottom of the page and how can I stop it? I got the code from a tutorial because this is my first attempt in coding a homepage by myself.

The author told me just to paste the code into the Body tag.

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".contactLink").click(function(){
                        if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                            $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
                        }
                    });
                });
                function closeForm(){
                    $("#messageSent").show("slow");
                    setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
               }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      function filterPath(string) {
        return string
          .replace(/^\//,'')
          .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
          .replace(/\/$/,'');
      }
      $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
        && location.hostname == this.hostname
        && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
          var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
           if ($target) {
             var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
             $(this).click(function() {
               $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
               var d = document.createElement("div");
            d.style.height = "101%";
            d.style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(d);
            window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
            setTimeout(function() {
            d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
                }, 10);
               return false;
             });
          }
        }
      });
    });
    /*! Smooth Scroll - v1.4.5 - 2012-07-22
    * Copyright (c) 2012 Karl Swedberg; Licensed MIT, GPL */
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not answer to your question I should have posted this message in comments but I don't have rights to do so,

Please provide some JSFiddle link or any other online tool link where we can test your script.

One guess to your problem is that you are somewhere increasing height greater then browser's height, for example try chang this:

```
            d.style.height = "101%";
```

to

```
            d.style.height = "50%";
```

and any other div which is exceeding screen height limit